# CORS issue with React and Localbase

Tags: reactjs, cors, indexeddb

I’ve already tried solutions from this forum, without success (which is why I’m creating this new post).

My app is just frontend (and all the solutions I've seen work from the backend).

I am trying to retrieve a base 64 image that I save with indexedDB.
But it throws me this error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://thetrymysadoroh.site/cu/gmlt3.js?eid=iobnfmmhgefpdgcdpocaceafmoocljnb' from origin 'https://cmf-app.netlify.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I use this library  ( Localbase) to save data in indexedDB:

https://github.com/dannyconnell/localbase

I get my data saved like this on the frontend:

```
const objCardPhoto = db.collection('cardsPhotos').doc('fileUpload0').get();
```

My goal is that when the browser reloads the image remains.

CODESANDBOX: https://codesandbox.io/s/localbase-img-download-rpto0?file=/src/components/CardUploadImage.jsx

[image]

```
import React, { useState} from "react";
import "../styles.css";
import Localbase from "localbase";

let db = new Localbase("db");

const CardUploadImage = () => {


  const objCardPhoto = db.collection("cardsPhotos").doc("photo1").get();

  const imgLocalbase = objCardPhoto.image;

  const [imgPreview, setImgPreview] = useState( imgLocalbase );

  const [error, setError] = useState(false);

  const handleImageChange = (e) => {

    setError(false);

    const selected = e.target.files[0];

    
    const ALLOWED_TYPES = ["image/png", "image/jpeg", "image/jpg"];
    if (selected && ALLOWED_TYPES.includes(selected.type)) {

      let reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onloadend = () => {
        setImgPreview(reader.result);
      };

      reader.readAsDataURL(selected);
    } else {
      setError(true);
    }
  };

  const handleSaveImage = () => {
    // create a collection ( 'cardsPhotos' ) and  document ( 'photo1' ) with Localbase
    db.collection("cardsPhotos").add(
      {
        image: imgPreview
      },
      "photo1"
    );

    alert("photo1 saved in indexedDB with Localbase");

    console.log("photo1 saved in indexedDB with Localbase");
  };

  const handleDeleteImg = () => {
    setImgPreview(null);

    db.collection("cardsPhotos").doc("photo1").delete();
  };

  return (
    <div  className="container">
      {error && <p className="errorMsg">File not supported</p>}
      <div
        className="imgPreview"
        style={{
          background: imgPreview
            ? `url("${imgPreview}") no-repeat center/cover`
            : "#131313"
        }}
      >
        {!imgPreview && (
          <>
            <label htmlFor="fileUpload" className="customFileUpload">
              CLICK for upload image
            </label>
            <input type="file" id="fileUpload" onChange={ handleImageChange } />
            <span>(jpg, jpeg o png)</span>
          </>
        )}
      </div>
      <div className="icons-card-canvas mb-5">
        <img
          className="icon-trash-canvas"
          src="/assets/images/trash.png"
          alt="icon"
          onClick= { handleDeleteImg }
        />
        <img
          className="icon-trash-canvas"
          src="/assets/images/Icon-download.png"
          alt="icon"
          onClick= { handleSaveImage }
        />
      </div>

      
    </div>
  );
};

export default CardUploadImage;
```

Comment: I believe all the solutions you've seen were for server side because that's where we tell the server to accept requests coming from other origins. Hence, enabling the CORS or `Cross Origin Request Sharing`

Comment: There is only one place where to solve a CORS issue. And that is the server. There are some whacky workarounds like a CORS proxy.  But the real solution is adding the respective CORS headers (like the other posts probably suggested) to the server-responses.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure the CORS policy is well configured on the API you're sending requests to, then this can be coming from the browser.
To get you going now, you can install a CORS extension on your browser like [this one for chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf?hl=en) and see.

Comment: While that may solve the issue for a single person or during development, installing a Chrome extension can hardly be seen as a solution for developer who develops a website or webapp to be used by many people. Or should OP force all his users to install that Crhome extension as well? The only place to solve a CORS issue is the server ... And if it's not under OP's control, that might be a sign, that that API is not meant to be called by the public ...

Comment: Thanks, I already installed a plugin in the browser but it didn't work. Maybe I have to configure something in the Localbase library ... because otherwise I don't have any api, my app is just frontend.